# How to use Hazelcast with MapStore

Tags: caching, hazelcast

I am using Hazelcast as caching Solution for my application.
My application has few inserts and updates to the database and these needs to be synced to Cache also.

I want to use MapStore functionality so that when I do IMap.put(), Hazelcast takes care of persisting the Object in underlying Db and also update its cache.

In the overridden store implementation, I want to call my DAO in following way to persist the Data.

```
public void store(Long key, Product value)
    {
        log.info("Storing Data for Employee {} in Database using DataStore ",     value);
    Long employeeId = employeeDao.create(value);
    value.setId(employeeId );

}
```

There are few issues listed below:-
1) In put call, I want to use "key" as the "employeeId", but this is generated only after insertion happens for this record in the Db. So how do I put into the Cache when I don't have the Id.? I want Hazelcast to use the "id" generated as part of store method call (or any other way) as the key to my Object.

> Imap.put(key,new Employee("name_of_Employee","age_of_employee"))

2) The MapStore implementation's store method returns a void so I cannot return the Id generated for this Object to the Client. How can I achieve this?
I tried using MapEntryListeners on the Map but the entry added callback does not return new Object. I also added PostProcessingMapStore interface to my MapStore but could not get the new Value back to client.

Please advice

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options:

1) Generate the `employeeId` outside of the database. You can use the [IdGenerator](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IdGenerator.html) from Hazelcast to do this.

2) If you must let the database generate the id, then you need to put the `Employee` in the cache manually AFTER it has been stored in the database.